# No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

This is somewhat weird behavior. I moved from Spring MVC to Spring Boot Configuration. This has caused the @Transactional method to throw the above error. Not sure why would switching from MVC to boot mvc do that. Anyone having nay idea about this?

I don't have specific code snippet as this is application wide and was working fine till I had Spring MVC. Now I moved to Spring Boot (Dependency upg. Filters moved etc.)

Flow for the methods having @Transactional is:

1. Action is called
2. If contains execute() which calls a Save method with @Transactional from a class which is implementation of an interface.
3. This class have another Dao method having @Transactional.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update the question with a little code snippet?

Comment: Hey, this is application wide and is not occuring at a specific code snipet. However, this happened post boot migration.

Comment: @MustafaYousef I had a doubt, can i have open Transactional annotation with Propagation as Mandatory and no parent method having Required Propagation?

Comment: Well, Mandatory does not create a transaction for you. So if it does not exist, it will only throw an exception whereas Required creates a new transaction if it does not exist.
So I would say the parent @Transactional  method who is calling those other methods should at least have one or create one itself.

Comment: I did replace the Parent method with Propagation.Required and it worked fine. I wanted to see The Propagation.Mandatory to fail so I created a dummy Controller - Service - Dao and Added only Propagation.Mandatory over the service and the Dao too. But it didn't fail. Now I am curious when should it actually fail.